# How to pass and receive json like function arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I pass & receive values to a javascript/jquery function as we pass in the functions of various plugins?
We pass parameters like this in the plugin function..

```
myFunction({
param1: '1',
param2: '2'
});
```

I just wanna know how to write the myFunction to receive the values?
Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: `function myFunction(data) { console.log(data.param1); }`

Comment: thanks for the comment. I tried your solution and found that, if I use console.log(data.param1) it's showing undefined. While if I just use data.param, it's working fine. What is that console.log than?

Comment: Paul, check my answer. You need to check and make sure the variable passed is what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have this

```
myFunction({
  param1: '1',
  param2: '2',
});
```

You can use it like this

```
var myFunction = function( data ) {
   var param1 = data.param1,
       param2 = data.param2;

   console.log(param1, param2, data);

};
```

Here's a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yzvk4/)**

You can also use functions like that too, like

```
myFunction({
  param1: '1',
  param2: '2',
  delay: function() {
     alert('here'); // This will happen after 5 seconds 
  }
});

var myFunction = function( data ) {
   var param1 = data.param1,
       param2 = data.param2;

   console.log(param1, param2, data);
   window.setTimeout(data.delay, 5000);

};
```

Here's a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yzvk4/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the rest of the thing, but what is the significance of console.log(param1, param2, data); ?

Comment: If you are using chrome you can open DevTools (F12) then click on console. the console is the best thing since sliced bread. you can see the output in the console. any error's in your javascript will show up there...ext if you go to the jsFiddle and click in the Result window then press F12 firebug will come up you can click on console in there as well to see the output of `console.log`

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction(vars){
  console.log((vars)?(vars.param1)?
    vars.param1:"param1 not defined":"vars not defined");
}
myFunction();
myFunction("hi");
myFunction({param1:22});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me that is the significance of console.log? I mean I've used it like vars.param1 and it's giving me the right output. So why everyone is using the console.log?
Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: @PaulShan It's used to show messages, try to open Chrome and in your code execute `console.log("Going to log window:",window);` Now open that page and press F12. You can see the console with the message. You can click on the `window` part of the message to see it's properties. Console.log doesn't do anything but showing you messages so you can see what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

"JSON-like function arguments" are just "an argument that is expected to be an object".

```
 function myFunction(obj) {
     console.log(obj);
 }
```